# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar la primera vocal de un string?

Tags: string, select, filtro, map, scala

Primero que nada, soy super novata en Scala, una disculpa si mi lenguaje no es el más técnico. Estoy trabajando con una columna de nombres de las que que necesito extraer la primera vocal, pero no se cómo incluir el filtro de vocal. Para las que necesité extraer la primera letra lo hacia con la siguiente función:

```
.withColumn("first_letter", substring(col("column_of_names"),0,1))
```

Cómo podría agregar el filtro de que sea la primera vocal? Encontré esto, pero no se como integrarlo a mi código:

```
val wordsFile = sc.textFile("myFile.txt")
val splitWords = wordsFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")) 
        .map(word => word.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", ""))
```

Mil mil gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenida, @Camila. En la pregunta deberías explicar algo más sobre el contexto de tu código. A ser posible, pon un código completo. Todo lo que puedas aportar servirá para que te podamos ayudar mejor. Supongo que estás trabajando con spark, pero no lo has dicho en ningún momento.